# Merge several physics bodies

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to merge several sprite nodes into a single unified physics body. For example:

[image]

I am trying to unify these three barriers into a single sprite node. I have looked at other questions and I have tried the following:

- Making one of the nodes the parent, adding the other nodes to the parent and setting them non-dynamic. However, this disables the movement of the children nodes.
- I tried creating a node with the a physics body of all the other barriers:

  ```
  SKPhysicsBody(bodies: self.allNodePhysicsBodies)
  ```
- I also tried creating a joint of the nodes with the "parent" node:

  ```
  let joint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: merge[0].physicsBody!, bodyB: merge[1].physicsBody!, anchor: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
  let joint1 = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: merge[0].physicsBody!, bodyB: merge[2].physicsBody!, anchor: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))


  self.physicsWorld.add(joint1)
  self.physicsWorld.add(joint)
  ```

  However, this does not unite the physics bodies. It does not create a single physics body.

How can I accomplish this? I was thinking my only option was to unite the textures before I even create the node.

**EDIT**

Attempt to unite the barriers with a physics body again:

```
    let ourUnionOfBodies = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [merge[0].physicsBody!, merge[1].physicsBody!, merge[2].physicsBody!])
    ourUnionOfBodies.isDynamic = true

    merge[2].physicsBody = ourUnionOfBodies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could draw the barriers inside a CGMutablePath and then use this as the physicsbody of one node, although it's a little long work to do.

```
let bodyPath = CGMutablePath()
bodyPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: ..., y: ...)) // Use move(to:) to “move the pen” somewhere without “drawing”
bodyPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ..., y: ...)) // Use addLine(to:) to trace a line starting from the “pen”’s last position to the specified CGPoint position
// ...
physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: bodyPath)
```

Comment: But then one node would have the body of 3 nodes? While the other two retain their individual bodies.

Comment: Yes, and you could set the physics bodies of the other 2 nodes to nil. The only part that I didn't understand well of your question is what type of behaviour do you expect from the 3 barriers. Presuming that you want all of the 3 barriers to move together, you could update the external barriers' positions (the barriers without physics bodies) inside override func update(...) by referring to the main node's position. Hoping that I was clear in my answer, let me know if it can help.

Comment: Ok so you suggest having the middle one with a body, and the outsider ones without a body, yet update their position every frame to simulate the vectors the middle node is receiving?

Comment: Yes exactly. By using a CGMutablePath you can draw a physicsBody that suites your needs as best.

Comment: I am just worried that updating them based on the position of the middle node could lead to small, yet visible discrepancies. For example, if the middle node is moving with a vector, I am not sure positioning the other two nodes off the position of the middle node will be accurate enough.

Comment: Yes I think there would be some small discrepancies. Maybe your best option is just to create a single spritenode which has the image of the 3 barriers, and then draw its physicsBody with a CGMutablePath.

Comment: That is the issue, I am not sure of what the amount of barriers I need, so I could need 10 or 20. They could be shaped in rows, boxes, rectangles, or different shapes depending on the level. I would have to make a different image for each scenario, which would not be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

[**init(bodies: [SKPhysicsBody])**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519736-init)

This is what you need.

However you're seemingly doing something wrong in using it. I assume what you're forgetting is to then set the properties of the newly created physics body to what you need for interaction with your world and other objects within it.

I'd make the same mistake, because I'd assume that all the properties of the unioned bodies would be adopted by the new body, particularly if they're all the same. But this is not the case.

From the docs:

> The properties on the children, such as mass or friction, are ignored.
>   Only the shapes of the child bodies are used.

So having created your new body from the union of the bodies in the array, now you need to manually set all the properties of this body as you desire/need.

eg.

```
// Putting the right bodies together, correctly

let ourUnionOfBodies = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [bodyMine, bodyBeyonce])
ourUnionOfBodies.isDynamic = YES!

// and the result = TWINS!
```

Comment: Can you be a little more verbose than "it did not work..." @pablo? You're not giving me ANYTHING to go on.

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of detail. So I applied the "ourUnionOfBodies" to the first node, but it still retained its original body, it does not have the body of all three nodes. I have pasted my code on my answer, at the bottom, on the "edit" section.

Comment: Ok, something is wrong in how you're putting the bodies together, or some other aspect of what you're doing is wrong. This should work. The express purpose of this init is to make a body from multiple bodies. It has not other purpose... having said that... I'd suggest starting a blank project, and making a couple of squares as bodies, and union joining them, just to make sure it actually works. There are bugs in SpriteKit. @pablo

Comment: did you look at my current code? Does it seem incorrect or could it be another part of the code?

Comment: Yes, it's likely your other code. You must "copy" across ALL settings you want from the original physics bodies. That includes categories, and EVERYTHING else, so that the new union body operates in the same way the bodies did before they were made a union.

Comment: By "copy" I mean you have to recreate the settings, all of them, that your previous physics bodies had. @pablo

Comment: You should follow this answer if you need to have a unique barrier. You can also don't need to do it if every single pieces of your barrier have the same physicsCategory. A barrier is a static element so the only task that it should perform is to stay where it stay: you can also decide to leave a piece opened or without physicsBody so to handle every single pieces as you wish..

Comment: My barriers move, so they can't be static @AlessandroOrnano